# bufferImage is not storing the new image

Tags: java

I observe one thing.

If I performed some of the operations on the bufferImage, like Loading image, drawing some graphics with the help of createGraphics() method,on restoring the same buffer image variable with the same JPEG image it is also showing the drawing performed by me on the previous buffer image.

```
class Controller {
static Thread second;
static Thread minutes;
static Thread hour;
static Logic l;
static Design d;
static SecondNiddle s;
static MinutNiddle m;
static HourNiddle h;
static BufferedImage img1 ;
Controller(){
Niddle n=new Niddle();
l=new Logic();
s=new SecondNiddle(l);
m=new MinutNiddle(l);
h=new HourNiddle(l);
d=new Design(l,n,s,m,h);
try {
img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("back1.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}


}

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{

Controller c=new Controller();
c.myThread();
while(true){
second.start();
second.join();

Temp.setClockBackGround(img1);
minutes.start();
minutes.join();
hour.start();
hour.join();
c.myThread();
}

}

public void myThread(){
second=new Thread(s,"second");
minutes=new Thread(m,"minutes");
hour=new Thread(h,"hour");
}
```

After performing the second thread operation if I reset the image and perform the following operations in minut thread.

```
public void run(){
l.minutAngle+=6;
create(Temp.getClockBackGround().createGraphics());
}
public void create(Graphics2D g){
System.out.println(l.minutAngle);
g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
g.drawLine(175,175,getX(115,l.minutAngle),getY(115,l.minutAngle));
g.dispose();
}
```

the same is happening in the hour thread and getx and logic will provide time and coordinates.Here is the Temp class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class Temp{

private  static BufferedImage background;

public static void setClockBackGround(BufferedImage bg){
background=bg;
}
public static BufferedImage getClockBackGround(){
BufferedImage b=background;

return b;
}
}
```

second thread

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;

    class SecondNiddle extends JPanel implements Runnable{
    public Graphics g;
    public Logic l;
    BufferedImage bg;
    Image img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("yourFile.gif");
    SecondNiddle(Logic l){
        this.l=l;
    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    setSize(358,380);   
    img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("back.jpg");

    }

    public void run(){


    for(int i=0;i<60;i++){
    try{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch(Exception e){}
    l.secondAngle+=6;
    repaint();  
    }
    }

    public void  paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(Temp.getClockBackGround(),0,0,null);
    System.out.println("running the paintComonent...");
        g.drawLine(175,175,getX(155,l.secondAngle),getY(155,l.secondAngle));
    g.dispose();
    }

    public int getX(int r,float angle){

    return (int)(175+(r*Math.sin(3.1416*angle/180)));
    }


    public int getY(int r,float angle){

    return (int)(175-(r*Math.cos(3.1416*angle/180)));
    }






    }
```

and the output is as below

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now I can see what you're trying to do. There are several issues here, but with a change in implementation a number of them will go away.

If you intend to have more than this graphic updating (like if this is part of a game) then you should really create a game loop that does the game logic and then the graphical updates at a fixed rate.

Barring that, if you want a clock background and just move the hands, the best way to do it is to create another empty buffered image with transparency, draw the hands on that, then create a composite of both the background buffered image and the hands buffered image. This requires you only loading the background once, and then reusing it for every update. Psuedo code:

```
public void init()
{
    ...
    BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read();
    BufferedImage foreground = new BufferedImage(background.width, 
        background.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB);
    BufferedImage composite = new BufferedImage(background.width, 
    background.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_ARGB);
    ....
}
....
public void paint()
{
    ...
    Gragphics2d g = (Graphics2d)composite.createGraphics();
    g2d.setComposite(
         AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 1.0));
    g.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
    g.drawImage(foreground,0,0,null);
    ...
}
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: That's not really enough to go on. Is this in a loop?  Are you creating new Temp objects or is it just one object? Where's the code you are using to actually draw? What are you doing with the BufferedImage after you draw? Try updating your question with the code (using the <code> tags) so we can see what it is you're doing.

Comment: try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("back1.jpg"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
Temp.setClockBackGround(img);
// here the img is buffferImage and Temp is class to store it with some setter and getter method.Later i Performed some drawingh.create(Temp.getClockBackGround().createGraphics()); later in create method i dispose the graphics also

Comment: I will rearrange my code and will tag in my question